# R: Auto Join Variables with Suffixes Created After Merge

Tags: r, join, merge

I am looking for a way join, into one column, the values of the same variable name, with different x an y suffixes, after merging dataframes.  For example: 'name.x' and 'name.y' would be joined into one column called 'name' where 'name.x' values would supersede 'name.y' values except for cases where 'name.x' has no value, in which case 'name.y' would be used.  I wish to do this for all columns with suffixes within the dataframe.

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), variable1.x=c('5.0',"",'7.9','NA','12'), variable1.y=c('1.5','3.0',"",'8.9','3.9') );

ID variable1.x variable1.y
1  5.0         1.5
2              3.0
3  7.9
4  NA          8.9
5  12          3.9
```

Expected output:

```
ID variable1
1  5.0
2  3.0
3  7.9
4  8.9
5  12
```

A sample of my data is below:

```
structure(list(cikcode = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20), yearendeddate = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("2000-12-30", "2001-12-29", "2002-12-28", 
"2004-01-03", "2005-01-01"), class = "factor"), source = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("10-K", "10-K405", 
"DEF 14A"), class = "factor"), sourcedate = structure(c(5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("2001-03-26", "2001-03-28", 
"2002-03-20", "2002-03-25", "2003-03-27", "2003-03-31", "2004-04-01", 
"2004-04-06", "2005-03-31", "2005-04-04"), class = "factor"), 
financialsdate = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("2000-12-30", "2001-12-29", "2002-12-28", 
"2004-01-03", "2005-01-01"), class = "factor"), ticker.x =        structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
statecode.x = structure(c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA), .Label = "NJ", class = "factor"), statename.x = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "NEW JERSEY", class =   "factor"), 
siccode.x = c(3823, NA, 3823, NA, 3823, NA, 3823, NA, 3823, 
NA), naicscode.x = c(334513, NA, 334513, NA, 334513, NA, 
334513, NA, 334513, NA), auditor.x = structure(c(3L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Arthur Andersen LLP", 
"Grant Thornton LLP", "KPMG LLP"), class = "factor"), auditfees.x =   structure(c(5L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("185,000", 
"225,000", "200,000", "137,100", "123,700"), class = "factor"), 
revenue.x = structure(c(3L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 2L, 
NA), .Label = c("84,912,000", "112,494,000", "68,231,000", 
"71,819,000", "94,676,000"), class = "factor"), earnings.x = structure(c(3L, 
NA, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = c("", "1,048,000", 
"3,284,000", "5,838,000"), class = "factor"), assets.x = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("47,644,000", 
"50,459,000", "54,421,000", "83,081,000", "93,016,000"), class = "factor"), 
ticker.y = c(NA, "", NA, "", NA, "", NA, "", NA, ""), statecode.y = c(NA, 
"NJ", NA, "NJ", NA, "NJ", NA, "NJ", NA, "NJ"), statename.y = c(NA, 
"NEW JERSEY", NA, "NEW JERSEY", NA, "NEW JERSEY", NA, "NEW JERSEY", 
NA, "NEW JERSEY"), siccode.y = c(NA, 3823, NA, 3823, NA, 
3823, NA, 3823, NA, 3823), naicscode.y = c(NA, "334513", 
NA, "334513", NA, "334513", NA, "334513", NA, "334513"), 
auditor.y = c(NA, "KPMG LLP", NA, "Arthur Andersen LLP", 
NA, "Arthur Andersen LLP", NA, "Grant Thornton LLP", NA, 
"Grant Thornton LLP"), auditfees.y = c(NA, "123,700", NA, 
"200,000", NA, "185,000", NA, "137,100", NA, "225,000"), 
revenue.y = c(NA, "68,231,000", NA, "84,912,000", NA, "71,819,000", 
NA, "94,676,000", NA, "112,494,000"), earnings.y = c(NA, 
"3,284,000", NA, "5,838,000", NA, "1,048,000", NA, "", NA, 
""), assets.y = c(NA, "50,459,000", NA, "54,421,000", NA, 
"47,644,000", NA, "83,081,000", NA, "93,016,000")), .Names = c("cikcode", 
"yearendeddate", "source", "sourcedate", "financialsdate", "ticker.x", 
"statecode.x", "statename.x", "siccode.x", "naicscode.x", "auditor.x", 
"auditfees.x", "revenue.x", "earnings.x", "assets.x", "ticker.y", 
"statecode.y", "statename.y", "siccode.y", "naicscode.y", "auditor.y", 
"auditfees.y", "revenue.y", "earnings.y", "assets.y"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey akrun, an example just added

Comment: Looks like you are online now.  Any feedback for the update?

Comment: Ive been trying to convert 3 of the variables to either characters, factors, or numeric and nothing is working.  R is just freezing on me after converting 6 of the preceding variables.  This is frustrating.

Comment: ok i ran it again.  It still give me the same error of undefined columns selected and NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: With your dput output I am not getting any error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the example showed, I thought you want `pmax`.  If you need to keep the 'variable1.x' values for values other than `''` or `NA`, you can use `ifelse`. In the example, the `"NA"` is not real NA.  You don't need to quote the NA values.  If it were real, we can use `is.na(df[,2])`

```
data.frame(df[1], variable=ifelse(df[,2] %in% c('','NA'), 
    as.numeric(as.character(df[,3])), as.numeric(as.character(df[,2]))),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#   ID variable
#1  1      5.0
#2  2      3.0
#3  3      7.9
#4  4      8.9
#5  5       12
```

If there are multiple columns, for e.g. 'df2'(here I am using real NAs), we split the 'variable' columns after removing the suffix part i.x. 'x', 'y' with `sub`.  Use `lapply` to loop over the `list` elements and get the result with `ifelse` as showed above.  Also, note that here I created 'character' columns using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

```
nm1 <- sub('\\..*$', '', names(df1)[-1])
df2 <- data.frame(ID= df1$ID)
df2[unique(nm1)] <-  lapply(split(names(df1)[-1],nm1), function(x) {
           x1 <- df1[x]
          as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(x1[,1])|x1[,1]=='', x1[,2], x1[,1]))})
df2
#   ID variable1 variable2
#1  1       5.0       4.2
#2  2       3.0       3.5
#3  3       7.9       3.2
#4  4       8.9       1.2
#5  5      12.0       4.0
```

We could also do this without `ifelse` by using `row/column` indexing

```
  df2[unique(nm1)] <-  lapply(split(names(df1)[-1], nm1), function(x) {
      x1 <- df1[x]
      as.numeric(x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1),((is.na(x1[,1])|x1[,1]==''))+1L)])})
```

#### Update

Based on the dput output in the OP's post ('df2')

```
 #subset the column names that have either `.x` or `.y` at the end
 v1 <- grep('\\.(x|y)$', names(df2), value=TRUE)
 #create another dataset with all columns except the ones in "v1"
 df2N <- df2[setdiff(names(df2), v1)]

 #change the 'factor' columns in 'v1' to 'character'    
 indx <- sapply(df2[v1], is.factor)
 df2[v1][indx] <- lapply(df2[v1][indx], as.character)

 #remove the suffix part ('.x', 'y') with `sub`
 nm1 <-sub('\\..*$', '', v1)
 #sort the unique elements of 'nm1' for naming new columns
 nm2 <- sort(unique(nm1))
 #create new columns after `split`ting the 'v1' with 'nm1'
 #merge the columns with the condition that if the first column
 # i.e. '.x' has NA or empty strings, replace that with the
 # second column element 
 df2N[nm2] <- lapply(split(v1, nm1), function(x) {
                  x1 <- df2[x]
      ifelse(is.na(x1[,1])|x1[,1]=='', x1[,2], x1[,1])})
 head(df2N,3)
 #  cikcode yearendeddate  source sourcedate financialsdate     assets auditfees
 #1      20    2002-12-28    10-K 2003-03-27     2002-12-28 50,459,000   123,700
 #2      20    2002-12-28 DEF 14A 2003-03-31     2002-12-28 50,459,000   123,700
 #3      20    2000-12-30    10-K 2001-03-26     2000-12-30 54,421,000   200,000
 #              auditor  earnings naicscode    revenue siccode statecode
 #1            KPMG LLP 3,284,000    334513 68,231,000    3823        NJ
 #2            KPMG LLP 3,284,000    334513 68,231,000    3823        NJ
 #3 Arthur Andersen LLP 5,838,000    334513 84,912,000    3823        NJ
 #   statename ticker
 #1 NEW JERSEY   <NA>
 #2 NEW JERSEY       
 #3 NEW JERSEY   <NA>
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(ID=1:5, variable1.x= c(5.0, '', 7.9, NA, 12), 
 variable1.y=c(1.5, 3.0, '', 8.9, 3.9), variable2.x= c(4.2, 3.5, '', NA, 4), 
 variable2.y=c(1.2, 1.5, 3.2, 1.2, NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to merge multiple columns (same name just different suffixes) within one dataframe and not within multiple dataframes. I am not sure how this applies exactly

Comment: I also needed to merge on more than just ID.  now that i have the separate rows i want I just wish to combine the values per row, disregarding any other variables that dont have the suffix (ie. no need to use ID here)

Comment: Since ID is not not necessarily unique for each row, would this affect the results?

Comment: Inputing my variable names into your code I ran the following            nm1 <- sub('\\..*$', '', names(merged_combined_files12)[-1])
df2 <- data.frame(cikcode= merged_combined_files12$cikcode)
df2[unique(nm1)] <-  lapply(split(names(merged_combined_files12)[-1],nm1), function(x) {x1 <- merged_combined_files12 [x]
as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(x1[,1])|x1[,1]=='', x1[,2], x1[,1]))}) .  However I get the error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(x1, , 2) : undefined columns selected
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I realized this needs to be tested first before I can test the others

Comment: I am confused.  Where where the columns variable1.x or variable1.y mentioned in the code you gave me?  I thought this code was valid for any columns with the prefixes x and y but I may be wrong.

Comment: Well im not a coding person so I cant follow your code.  I just wish I could get something to combine the columns for me without having the specify the column names. I thought your code did this but from what you are saying now I am not sure

Comment: I keep getting the same error: Error: unexpected symbol in "df2[unique(nm1)] ....."

Comment: Your example is fine.  It is just not working for my particular dataframe and I don't know why.

Comment: my dataset is to large for dput

Comment: Just included an example of my data. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this issue is to handle it at the moment of the merge.

My package [safejoin](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin) features joins that can handle these conflicts

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)

df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), variable1=c('5.0',"",'7.9','NA','12'))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), variable1=c('1.5','3.0',"",'8.9','3.9'))

safe_left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID", conflict = ~ dplyr::coalesce(
  as.numeric(as.character(.x)), as.numeric(as.character(.y))))
#   ID variable1
# 1  1       5.0
# 2  2       3.0
# 3  3       7.9
# 4  4       8.9
# 5  5      12.0
```

If you can afford to clean your data beforehand and start from numeric columns it would
just have been :

```
safe_left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID", conflict = dplyr::coalesce)
```